# How to fire a process builder after a document is added to an oppty/object

Tags: attachment, fileupload

I have a case, where upon adding a file/attachment to an opportunity, I need to send that attachment, as an email.

I don't want to use the trigger:

```
trigger trialFileUpload on ContentDocument (after insert) {
    system.debug('Trigger: A new File is uploaded!');
    // send email here!
}
```

I want to use Process builder and flow. Any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, process builder on content objects is not supported. You can vote the idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E35YQAS) and maybe it can make it to the roadmap.

Alternatively, you can write a trigger on the Content object to update related opportunity and you can always write a process builder on the opportunity but it would seem counter-intuitive based on your scenario.